# has_many + accepts_nested_attributes_for + :update_only => true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

As I learned update_only doesn't work for has_many association.

I am updating nested attributes and it creates new children each time and don't delete old children. What would be the good way to delete them automatically on each update (to mimic :update_only behavior which works for has_one)?

I know about :allow_destroy. However, I don't have children id's to let rails know what should be destroyed.

P.S. I asked this question originally back in 2012 and back then I found a hacky solution to override assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association. I wonder whether anything was introduced in Rails to solve this problem. It looks like very common straightforward case. I wonder why there is a built-in solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach which I found is to override method assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association on the object, check association type in there. if it's has_many then do destroy_all on this association.

Such code can be generalized and moved to a module for further reuse.

Comment: BTW. This solution became more problematic in Rails 4. It looks like assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association became more complex  and as result it's harder to override while handling all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a better solution in town mentioned in these two questions:

- [Rails 4 has_many nested_attributes to replace all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591636/rails-4-has-many-nested-attributes-to-replace-all)
- [Rails replace collection intead of adding to it from a has_many nested attributes form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161314/rails-replace-collection-intead-of-adding-to-it-from-a-has-many-nested-attribute)

The solution is

```
def foo_attributes=(*attrs)
  self.foo.clear
  super(*attrs)
end
```