# Rails replace collection instead of adding to it from a has_many nested attributes form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have these models (simplified for readability):

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :business_hours, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :business_hours
end

class BusinessHour < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :place
end
```

And this controller:

```
class Admin::PlacesController < Admin::BaseController
  def update
    @place = Place.find(params[:id])

    if @place.update_attributes(place_params)
      # Redirect to OK page
    else
      # Show errors
    end
  end

  private

  def place_params
    params.require(:place)
      .permit(
        business_hours_attributes: [:day_of_week, :opening_time, :closing_time]
      )
  end
end
```

I have a somewhat dynamic form which is rendered through javascript where the user can add new opening hours. When submitting these opening hours I would like to always replace the old ones (if they exist). Currently if I send the values via params (e.g.):

```
place[business_hours][0][day_of_week]: 1
place[business_hours][0][opening_time]: 10:00 am
place[business_hours][0][closing_time]: 5:00 pm
place[business_hours][1][day_of_week]: 2
place[business_hours][1][opening_time]: 10:00 am
place[business_hours][1][closing_time]: 5:00 pm
```

... and so forth

These new business hours get added to the existing ones. Is there a way to tell rails to always replace the business hours or do I manually have to empty the collection in the controller every time?

Comment: You can also pass `include_id: false` as an option to `fields_for` instead of allowing rails to generate the `id` hidden field and then filtering it out using the `permit` method

Answer (score 9):

Bit optimizing the solution proposed @robertokl, to reduce the number of database queries:

```rb
def business_hours_attributes=(*args)
  self.business_hours.clear
  super(*args)
end
```

Comment: `self.business_hours.clear` doesn't trigger callbacks (at least the `before_destroy` isn't called), so I prefer @robertokl's answer

Comment: Clear doesn't destroy anything, it just removes the association so there is no reason destroy callbacks should be called

Answer (score 7):

This is the best I could get:

```
def business_hours_attributes=(*attrs)
  self.business_hours = []
  super(*attrs)
end
```

Hopefully is not too late.

Comment: this is a problem that I had a long time ago and now again, probably at the first time what I did was not so elegant than this solution. Thanks you!

Comment: This does not seem to work properly with Rails 6. AR tries to set parent id to nil on child records, and it triggers not null violation (with default migrations). IDK if this behaviour changed between Rails versions.

Answer (score 0):

You miss id of business_hours try:

```
def place_params
    params.require(:place)
      .permit(
        business_hours_attributes: [:id, :day_of_week, :opening_time, :closing_time]
      )
end
```

That's why the form is adding a new record instead of updating it.

Comment: Thanks, but I am deliberately omitting the :id parameter. I don't want to update any records. I always want to replace the existing records with the new ones sent via the form.

Comment: @JorikHanssen without an uniq identifier I'm afraid you cannot do the 'delete' part of the 'replace' you wanted to do. And also you should not send `update_attributes` in your controller, the 'replace' logic is probably better suited in your `BusinessHour` model. I hope this make sense.