# Rails 4 has_many nested_attributes to replace all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I want to use nested_attributes to replace all my old associated objects by the new ones. How is the best way to do that?

If I use the code below, every time I update my main object with nested_attributes, new objects associated are created.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :days
```

**Edit**

I´ve got it with the `before_validation` callback below:

```
def replace_days
  db_days = days.where('id IS NOT NULL')

  all_days = days
  all_days -= db_days

  self.days = all_days
end
```

The problem with that is my unique validation on the child model. Rails is going to the database to validate uniqueness. Since my replacement is not on database at the validation moment, got validation error. Don´t know how to bypass this and if this is the best way to do that. I hope that rails have some native function or parameter that helps me to do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I could get:

```
def days_attributes=(*attrs)
  self.days = []
  super(*attrs)
end
```

Hopefully is not too late.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `reject_if` option like the following:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :days, reject_if: :all_blank
```

This should prevent the behaviour you described.

Comment: Don´t know if I was clear enought, I need to replace all my old `days` to the `days` from nested attributes.